# Java IF statements non-functioning (Android studio) - Compiler has developed free will

Tags: java, android, if-statement, string-comparison

This problem has been driving me nuts for the past four days as I have not for the life of me been able to figure out whether the compiler is in fact trolling me and is purposely refusing to execute my code or whether I have indeed ‘missed a trick’ and have done something wrong.

Anyways consider the following code present in one of my activity methods.

```
    cFactory = new cFpro()
    cFactory.wasCollStrC(user1.getClass().getSimpleName(), 
    mList.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName(), 8);
```

Co-operating with the following class:

```
public class cFpro {

private boolean inContact;
private static final String cB = "ball";

public cFpro(){

}

public boolean wasCollStrC(String s1, String s2, int d){  //cant compare arguments in if statement properly
    if (d == 8) {    
        //if (s1.equals(s1) {
        return true; //Code always skipped.

    }
    return false;
}


public boolean isInContact() {
    return inContact;
}

}
```

At first I thought there was an issue with the way I was collecting the class names and other variables however I experimented by comparing simple statements which always evaluate to true.

Consider the bit in the “wasColStrC” method. When passed the following arguments the corresponding if statement ALWAYS skips the return “true” bit and DOES NOT execute the code within the statement.

```
cFactory.wasCollStrC(“Tree”,”Ball”,8);
```

With the if statement set to these condition, despite them being true, the code within their “ifs” are not executed. 
I have tried:

•   Making both the class and methods all possible combinations of static and non static.

•   Reinstalling the compiler

•   Moving the "if" comparison within the method itself.

•   Moving the method so that it is wihin the activitiy, i.e. this.wasCollStrC((“Tree”,”Ball”,8))

In all cases the following if statements,

```
public boolean wasCollStrC(String s1, String s2, int d){  
    if(F){  
        //Execute Code
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

With the following arguments:

```
cFactory.wasCollStrC(“tree”,”ball”,8);
```

Where 'F' is any of the following conditions, despite being reported as true by the compiler itself, ALWAYS HAS THE CODE WITHIN IT SKIPPED by said compiler for whatever reason.

```
if (d == 8)
if (s1.equals(s1)) 
if(s2.equals(“ball”)
if(s1.equals(“tree”)
if(cB.equals(Cb))
if ("b".equals("b"))
```

However this one works.

```
If(1 == 1)
```

I have tried my utmost and absolute best to explain the problem as clearly and as precisely as i can. Does anybody have any insight, solutions or advice as to how to fix this problem and make the code execute as it is supposed to?

Cheers!

Comment: LOL 'Compiler has developed free will'.  It has become sentient?  Does it have access to weapons?  Do I need to stock up on canned food and bottled water?

Comment: Condition is not the problem, problem is what you are doing with the return value, show us where you are using the return value of this method.

Comment: I thought for a moment that puting both returns in if else statement would help, but then of course realised that the first return on true will cause exit from method straight away ( docs       https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html). So @Shadov seems right to me, conditions seem fine.